# ConstraintLayout, set tools:layout_editor_absoluteX programmatically

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How can I change the "tools: layout_editor_absoluteX" variable in Java code?

I can change this variable in XML as follows:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="10dp"
```

Now how do I do this in Java code?

**EDIT**

How can I change the position x and y of a view in ConstraintLayout? (programmatically)

In any way possible

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change the "tools: layout_editor_absoluteX" variable in Java code?

You can't. All of the attributes in the `tools` namespace are purely for the IDE or other tools. They do not even *exist* at runtime, let alone be something that you change.

Comment: How to do when it is `app`, specifically for `ConstraintLayout`?

Comment: @RohanKandwal: Use Java/Kotlin code to call methods on `ConstraintLayout` and related classes.